# What options are out there for an embeddable WYSIWIG text editor?

Tags: wysiwyg, embedded-control, text-editor

I'm thinking something along the lines of [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Please include a list of features.

Examples include:

- supports text formatting
- supports links
- supports images
- syntax types (markdown/wiki/etc)
- licensing and/or pricing
- customizibility
- plugin support
- browser compatibility

*Note: Please limit the answers to one editor per answer to preserve cleanliness*

**Update: Forgot to add browser compatibility to the list**

Comment: Really? That's it? TinyMCE and CKEditor? I thought there'd be more.

Comment: I'd love to hear some limitations/problems with these, at the moment it's just the positives!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

- Open Source (Free)
- Clean output
- Fast loading
- Great [javascript API](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/)
- Lots of [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/)
- Lots of great samples in various programming frameworks
- You can easily build plugins
- You can easily create [custom toolbar functionality](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Dialog_Customization)
- Supports [custom file browsers](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_(Uploader)/Custom_File_Browser) in addition to the [one they sell](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x)
- Very easy to install and configure
- Has a large user base
- It has nifty [jQuery adapter](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter)

Answer (score 2):

## [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org)

> … a semantic Rich Text Editor framework written in Javascript with
>   best support of xHTML5.

[Features](http://aloha-editor.org/features.php)

Subheadings from that page:

- Aloha Editor Links …
- Repositories - connect everything …
- No reload. No popup. No need to preview …
- Editing and formatting text without markup …
- The floating menu. A brand new lightweight context menu. …
- Tables for the web. …
- Faster. …
- WYSIWYG for dynamic content. …
- Contenteditable. HTML5 available - now. …
- Get what you expect. …

Selected as the editor of choice for the interface of [Booktype](http://www.sourcefabric.org/en/booktype/).

> … five clear advantages to using it.
>
> 1. **In-context editing.** Aloha, unlike WYSIWYG editors, actually lets you edit the page rather than the text abstracted from the page.
>      This makes for a much nicer editing experience and opens up a lot of
>      other possibilities for interacting with the page.
> 2. **Good development activity.** The Aloha team are very approachable and active. We talked to a couple of the core dev team and are happy
>      that they are easy going and seem good to work with.
> 3. **Uses JQuery.** Aloha just changed to JQuery libs recently which is great because Booktype also uses a lot of JQuery so it minimalises
>      the possibilities for conflict and lowers the number of external
>      libraries required.
> 4. **In-browser design a step closer.** Aloha interacts directly with HTML5 content editable regions without changing the structure of the
>      page which means any CSS applied is unmediated and can be effected
>      directly by the user.
> 5. **Can work with external Javascripts.** Because Aloha doesn't change the structure of the page (as per above) any external JS libs
>      can work directly on the content without needing to be altered.

Answer (score 1):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

- Easy to integrate  - Only a few lines of code needed.
- Customizable - Themes and plugins, block invalid elements and force attributes.
- Browserfriendly - Mozilla, MSIE, FireFox, Opera, Safari and Chrome.
- Lightweight - PHP/.NET/JSP/Coldfusion GZip compressor, Makes TinyMCE 75% smaller and a lot faster to load.
- AJAX Compatible - You can easily use AJAX to save and load content!
- International - Multilanguage support using language packs.
- Open Source - Free under the LGPL license, millions of ppl help test and improve this editor every day.