# WYSIWYG editor that outputs to markdown

Tags: wysiwyg, markdown

Is there a WYSIWYG editor that outputs markdown?

Comment: The whole point of markdown was so that a WYSIWYG editor was not necessary.

Comment: Correct, but Markdown is a good interchange language between programmers and writers. So a WYSIWYG editor would be a good thing to have. That, and Markdown doesn't do tables -- you have to use HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://hallojs.org/demo/markdown/

Comment: Hallo works but try pasting some rich text, e.g. the Hallo.js is free software developed by Henri Bergius for the IKS Project and co-funded by the European Union" part at the bottom (copy it from its page, not from here). You'll see a ton of markup junk when you paste.

Answer (score 1):

One excellent editor/writer on the Mac OS X platform is [iA Writer](http://www.iawriter.com/). It's is beautiful and simple to use.

If you're looking for web-based options, look at [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

[See this answer also.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/254/what-options-are-out-there-for-an-embeddable-wysiwig-text-editor)

Comment: OMG, thats not WYSIWYG, and not web-based.

Comment: You did not ask for web-based, updated answer for web-based stuff!

Comment: it needs to output markdown...